# Bootstrap Column Empty spaces when using a transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails application that uses a model to populate the index page. The index page is displayed using bootstrap columns and rows. I added a transition to make the boxes taller on hover. I like how they look when the first one in a row is hovered over but when the middle or last box becomes tall, it leaves empty spaces to the left. I have googled extensively but I am either searching the wrong things or missing something.

My question is: How can I make it so that the empty spaces to the left of the tall box are filled with small boxes so that it looks the same to the right and left.
I am open to javascript/jQuery solutions if necessary.

Thank you in advance!

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSAPv.png)

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlZHp.png) Empty space to the left of the box

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Edit: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheZenMaster/v1vyvdx2/2/) of the basic code that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="box" id="a">A</div>
  [...]
</div>
```

And css:

```
.box {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition:height 0.5s; /* Animation time */
  -webkit-transition:height 0.5s; /* For Safari */
  &:hover {
    height: 50px;
  }

  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
    position: static;
}
.masonry {
    column-count: 4;
}
```

Its currently fixed to 4 columns per row, but you can change that by changing `column-count` dynamically using `@media (min-width: ...px) {}` to suite your need!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am trying out the code and the column farthest to the right does not remain balanced when the boxes are expanded. Is there a way around that? I would like all the columns to contain a similar amount of boxes if possible.